# Convert to type declared in Class Type

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

folks,
 I have a method in i pass object of type Type. And i want to convert object that i have in this method, to type in Type. For example

```
void SetNewRecord(Type requiredType)
{
  var list = GridView.DataSource as requiredType;
  for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
  {
    if (list[i].KOD == kod)
    {
      GridView.CurrentCell = GridView[0, i];

      return;
    }
  }
}
```

if i pass int[] as parameter, i want that GirdView.DataSource be converted to int[]. Is it possible in C# ?

Comment: Your loop is written as if you already *know* it will be an array. Do you know this?

Comment: I don't understand how you can get this to run with an `int[]`. What should `list[i].KOD` do with it?

Comment: Yes, i know that it will array. As for int[] - i used example with int for simplicity, actually there will be user defined class, that will have property KOD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use Generic to solve your problem

```
public interface ISample
{
    object KOD {get;set;} 
}

void SetNewRecord<T>() where T : ISample
{
     var list = GridView.DataSource as IEnumerable<T>;
     // implement needed logic here
}
```

And if you want to call it via reflection

```
 MethodInfo castMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("SetNewRecord").MakeGenericMethod(type);
 castMethod.Invoke(null, null);
```

Comment: OP is asking if he can cast via reflection. I showed him how. Implementing logic in method is his task

Comment: That's good idea to use generic method here, i thought about it, but we need to check property of class T(I know that each class T will have property KOD, that i need to check). Using generic we can't do it.

Comment: You can create interface with KOD property and inherit your classes from this interface. Than you can specify that you want to pass only types derived from this interface. See my edit